# При выхода из цикла while внутри for цикл for так же прерывается. Почему и что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется кусок кода:

```
for element in questions:
    while answer != 'д' and answer != 'н':
        answer = input(element+': ')
        answer = (((answer[0].lower()).replace('y', 'д')).replace('n', 'н'))  
        if answer != 'д' and answer != 'н':
            print('Ответ невозможно принять.')
```

При благополучном ответе прерывается так же и цикл for.
Если убрать while цикл for работает нормально.
Объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит и где я допустил ошибку.

Comment: Язык - Python 3

Answer (score 1):

```
def parse_answers(question):
    while True:
       answer = input('{}: '.format(question))[0].lower()
       if answer not in ('y', 'n'):
          print('Ответ невозможно принять')
          continue
       else:
          return answer

questions = ('yes?', 'no?')
for question in questions:
   answer = parse_answers(question)
   print(answer)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score -1):

Ошибку понял, добавил в конце `answer = ''`.

Comment: лучше в отдельную функцию вопрос к пользователю вынесите: `for q in questions: ask_question(q)` (тогда `answer` с предыдущей итерации не будет мешать). Условие можно упростить: `if not answer.casefold().startswith(('yes','no', 'да', 'нет')): print('Ответ невозможно принять.') else: break`